# A standard variant of the Lefschetz principle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am studying [this](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/21974276/degeneration-of-the-hodge-de-rham-spectral-sequence-y0-) paper, and I am a little confused about the terminology *"a standard variant of the Lefschetz principle"*.

Assume I have a smooth and proper morphism of schemes $X\longrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(k)$, where $k$ is a field. Assume that $X$ is connected. The author writes:

> A standard variant of the ''Lefschetz principle'' guarantees the
> existence of the following very noncanonical data: a finitely
> generated $\mathbb{Z}$-Algebra $A$, a ring homomorphism $A\longrightarrow k$, a smooth proper $A$-scheme $\mathfrak{X}$, and an isomorphism $\mathfrak{X}_{k}\cong X$.

What exactly is he talking about here? Is $\mathfrak{X}$ some sort of a Néron model, and how do I construct it (or prove its existence)? Why does (as is claimed by Eric Wofsey's answer) Chow's Lemma help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just saying that defining the scheme $X$ involves only finitely many elements of $k$.  Cover $X$ with finitely many affine $k$-schemes.  Each of these affine $k$-schemes are actually defined over some finitely generated subring of $k$, since the corresponding $k$-algebras have a presentation that involves only finitely many specific elements of $k$.  To glue these affine $k$-schemes together, you just have to cover their pairwise intersections with finitely many affine open subschemes, which again is witnessed by finitely many elements of $k$.  To witness that these $k$-algebras are smooth over $k$ uses finitely many more elements of $k$.  To witness that the scheme you get by gluing them together is proper again needs only finitely many elements of $k$ (using Chow's lemma).

Taken together, this gives a finitely generated subring $A\subseteq k$ which contains all the elements of $k$ needed to construct the scheme $X$ and prove it is smooth and proper over $k$.  So, you can carry out this construction and obtain a smooth and proper scheme $\mathfrak{X}$ over $A$ which becomes $X$ after base-changing to $k$.

Comment: Can you elaborate that in a little more détail? Much of what you wrote is still unclear to me. For instance: (1.) how do I know that $X$ can be covered by finitely many affine $k$-schemes? Who tells me that we are quasi-compact? (2.) How do I know that the $k$-Algebras corresponding to the affines only have finitely many specific elements of $k$. Excuse me if I am stupid or just not seeing the wood for all the trees here.

Comment: A proper morphism is by definition finite type.  So $X$ is covered by finitely many affine $k$-schemes, each of which is Spec of a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

Comment: what do you mean by "To witness these k-algebras are smooth over $k$ uses finitely many more elements of $k$"? How does Chow's lemma help me in this?